# PHP Warning with unlink even when checking that file exists

Tags: php, opencart, unlink

I have the following code:

```
if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

Which gives me this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  unlink(/var/www/korea-cosmetics/data/www/korea-cosmetics.ru/system/cache/cache.category.seopath.1547731925): No such file or directory in /var/www/korea-cosmetics/data/www/korea-cosmetics.ru/system/library/cache.php on line 60
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you or the web server account has the rights to delete it, Are you sure, as its  a cache file that the system has not already deleted it.

Comment: As its a cache file, I would expect that the caching system ought to be asked to delete it, or the cache will get in a real mess and cause you other problems. It sounds like the system is protecting itself from you :)

Comment: It's a part of a system, I don't delete these files on my own. The problem is in these warnings that were there from the beginning. I just don't understand why file_exists and is_file are letting it in. Can it be ownership issue?

Comment: Are you sure that it is error of your code? Comments your code and check error is exist or gone. Because usually this error is common in opencart

Comment: I think this is opencart error. I just don't like my log file being polluted, so I'm trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists` and `is_file` can accept relative path, but `unlink` doesn't. So, we have to convert the relative path to an absolute one.

```
unlink(realpath($file)); // this should suffice
```

Relative path looks like: `../../path/to/file.php`

Absolute path looks like: `/path/to/file.php`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Grin AFAIK, this is the only reason why both `file_exists` and `is_file` would return true but `unlink` still wouldn't work. Let me know if you find something else.